# Convert Javascript XMLHttpRequest to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

Can this code be converted to jQuery code? For example by using: `jQuery.get()`. Although I don't think there is an `responsetype` `arraybuffer`.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = function() {
  // do stuff
}

request.send();
```

**EDIT**

I'm trying to make a Chrome HTML5 Web Audio plugin for jQuery. So I'm trying to `jQuerify` where possible. Check out what I try to convert @ http://pieterhordijk.com/sandbox/html5-audio-api/webkit-audiocontext-interface/adding-a-basic-control

Word of caution don't click the play button with the volume high as you can only stop it for now with a refresh of the page :)

Comment: Your `onload` should read `onreadystatechange`. [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#responseType) is only supported from FF >= 6.

Comment: @Marcel: What is FF? And Why would I change onload to onreadystatechange?

Comment: FF = Firefox; `onload` is not a property of [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) objects.

Comment: Well the stuff I'm working on is experimental (Chrome canary build). So you might be right about the browser support. And I need to use onload in stead of onreadystatechange.

Comment: Aha, that makes things more clear. But why do you need to use `onload`?

Comment: @Marcel: Sorry for the confusion. I don't know whether I really need it, but it doesn't work if I don't :) I'll update my question to make things more clear. 1 sec.

Comment: I can't test this, my Chromium is not new enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    // do useful things with data
});
```

Adjust parameters as you like, see [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).